# When I run a tensorflow model on GPU, what if I want to set some operations to CPU?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, out-of-memory

I am training a tesorflow model on the GPU, but always get out of memory problem, so I want to set some of the operations to be run on CPU. Here is my code:
I set this in the main function:

```
    gpus = tf.config.list_physical_devices(device_type='GPU')
    tf.config.experimental.set_visible_devices(gpus[0],'GPU')
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpus[0], enable=True)
```

And in the class(tf.keras.Model), for one of the function that needs to be called by **init**, I set

```
    def _setup_C(self, double_length=False):
            """ Construct C~ from C
    
            double_length: current C is for length L, convert it to length 2L
            """
            with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
                C = _r2c(self.C)
                self._setup_state()
                dA_L = power(self.L, self.dA)
                # Multiply C by I - dA_L
                C_ = _conj(C)
                prod = contract("h m n, c h n -> c h m", tf.transpose(dA_L,perm = [0,2,1]), C_)
                if double_length: prod = -prod # Multiply by I + dA_L instead
                C_ = C_ - prod
                C_ = C_[..., :self.N] # Take conjugate pairs again
    
                self.C = tf.identity(_c2r(C_))
    
                if double_length:
                    self.L *= 2
                    self._omega(self.L, dtype=C.dtype, cache=True)
```

But it seems that it does not help with the problem, does anyone has some ideas for it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use tf.device(),which specifies the device to be used for ops created/executed in a particular context. For example,i want to store the tensors on the CPU and perform a matrix multiplication operation on the GPU.

```
tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)

# Place tensors on the CPU
with tf.device('/CPU:0'):
  a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
  b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])

# Run on the GPU
c = tf.matmul(a, b)
print(c)
```

Output of the above code:

```
Executing op MatMul in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
tf.Tensor(
[[22. 28.]
 [49. 64.]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32)
```

Thank You.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have a little question for your prooposed solution that if I use the tf.device this way (place the tensor on CPU and do the operation on GPU), will it affect the GPU utility as tensors will be continuously transfer between CPU and GPU.